# Rename function for data frame columns

Tags: r

I am trying to make a function that gets as input a data frame and two names (old and new) and replaces the column old name of the data frame with the new name. I tried

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 8:10)


my.rename <- function(df, old.name, new.name){
 names(df)[names(df) == old.name] <- new.name 
}
my.rename(df, "a", "something")
df
```

and also

```
my.rename <- function(df, old.name, new.name){
 eval(substitute(names(df)[names(df) == old.name] <- new.name), df)
}
my.rename(df, "a", "something")
df
```

but the name doesn't seem to be affected.

Comment: You need to assign your result. Try `df <- my.rename(...)`. The reason is that R use copy-on-modify rules. (With some exceptions) you can't modify an object in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need only return the dataframe as modifed in the function:

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 8:10)


my.rename <- function(df, old.name, new.name){
 names(df)[names(df) == old.name] <- new.name 
 df
}
df2 <- my.rename(df, "a", "something")
df2
```